# Excel Macro multiline find-condition-and insert

Tags: vba, excel

i have an excelsheet column 'Ranges' wherein i have multiline text in random order. I need to find specific prefix in multiline text and paste it next column.

Objective is to find Prefix in order of DS>FP>NP>HE and so on wherein if DS prefix is not present FP is taken and so on.

Sample sheet result looks like following:-

[image]

I have following code till now please help me to solve this assignment:-

```
Sub Rangess()

   Dim colNum As Integer
   colNum = ActiveSheet.rows(1).Find(What:="Range", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "NEW"

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use Split to separate the multiline text, and Left to get the first 2 letters. To find the prefix you could use the Select ... Case function or multiple if statements if you prefer.

Comment: thanks matts, I am novice to macro making could you please help me out

Comment: sure I can help, but please research and attempt to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code which I have tested on the test case you provided and its working fine.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim colNum As Integer
    colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Range", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "NEW"

    'counting no of rows
    Dim No_Of_Rows As Long
    No_Of_Rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim Range_col_val As Variant
    Dim split_Range_col As Variant
    Dim Range_splited_cell_val As Variant
    Dim Prefix As Variant
        Prefix = Array("DS", "FP", "NP", "HE")
    Dim FLAG As Boolean
    Dim j As Integer



    'Looping for rows

    For i = 2 To No_Of_Rows

        'Extracting Data from col Range

        Range_col_val = Cells(i, colNum).Value
        split_Range_col = Split(Range_col_val, vbLf)
        j = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, colNum + 1).Value = split_Range_col(0)
        FLAG = False
        While FLAG = False And j < 5
            'Looping for Each Line in Col Range
            For k = LBound(split_Range_col) To UBound(split_Range_col)
                Range_splited_cell_val = split_Range_col(k)
                If (Range_splited_cell_val Like Prefix(j) & "*") Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, colNum + 1).Value = Range_splited_cell_val
                    FLAG = True
                End If
            Next k
            j = j + 1
        Wend
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edited the code to write 1st line if none of the selections work.

Comment: thanks mohit what to use in case if none of my selection is present in mutliline text and I want first line to be pasted in NEW column

Comment: I have edited the code above for this only u need to set the 1st line in the starting only so if match is found then the col value will change otherwise it will be the 1st line from Range

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub test()

Dim colNum As Long
   colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:="Range", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "NEW"          


 Dim Arr As Variant
 Dim Lr As Long, R As Long
 Dim i As Long, n As Long
 Dim V As String, F As String

 Lr = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row     
 Arr = Array("DS", "FP", "NP", "HE")

 For R = 2 To Lr
    V = Cells(R, colNum).Value
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
     n = InStr(V, Arr(i))
     If n <> 0 Then
      F = Mid(V, n)
      If InStr(F, vbLf) <> 0 Then F = Split(F, vbLf)(0)
      Cells(R, colNum + 1).Value = F
      Exit For
     End If
    Next
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Fadi what to use in case if none of my selection is present in mutliline text and I want first line to be pasted in NEW column